# Extracting data from json

Tags: php, json

I want to retrieve only the mp4 url ( `http://vid.lsw.example.com/_videos_t4vn23s9jc5498tgj49icfj4678/0000267/_mp4/0267665.mp4?st=BHmB0h98u4JIGsbmnPKrbQ&e=1436437792`) from the json.

```
{
  "title": "testvideo",
  "_filename": "testvideo-267665.mp4",
  "playlist_index": null,
  "webpage_url_basename": "267665",
  "http_headers": {
    "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/20.0 (Chrome)",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5"
  },
  "requested_subtitles": null,
  "format": "0 - unknown",
  "webpage_url": "http://www.example.com/267665",
  "playlist": null,
  "ext": "mp4",
  "extractor": "testExtract",
  "thumbnails": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "url": "http://img.l3.cdn.example.com/_thumbs/0000267/0267665/0267665_002m.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "format_id": "0",
  "id": "267665",
  "url": "http://vid.lsw.example.com/_videos_t4vn23s9jc5498tgj49icfj4678/0000267/_mp4/0267665.mp4?st=BHmB0h98u4JIGsbmnPKrbQ&e=1436437792",
  "extractor_key": "TestExtract",
  "fulltitle": "TestVideo",
  "display_id": "267665",
  "thumbnail": "http://img.example.com/_thumbs/0000267/0267665/0267665_002m.jpg"
}
```

Comment: possibly its a typo but your json is broken.

Comment: yes it is correct json is broken

Comment: @ikrabbe fixed the json...messed up while i copy paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$yt_info = json_decode($yt_json);

echo $yt_info->{'thumbnails'}[0]->{'url'}; //for image
echo $yt_info->url; //for url
```

yt_info is object so use like the above statement. and also correct your json format

Comment: I fixed my json + made things clear...please check again

Comment: @user2650277 the above answer will work for your case try it

Comment: its not working here.i got the thumbnail like this `$thumb = $yt_info['thumbnail'];`

Comment: don't use associative array use this json_decode($yt_json) instead of json_decode($yt_json,true)

Comment: Thanks it worked but why its not possible via associative array.Its a more cleaner approach in my book

Comment: it will also works with associative array also. lot of conversation will takes place. you can directly use  $yt_info['url']

Comment: here is the sample https://ideone.com/RluJHn i think you have parsing problem only at start

Answer (score 0):

To get the url string, simply use

`$yt_info->url`